# How to patch VMware Player 3.1.5 for 32 bit machine with new Lubuntu 12.10 Kernel?

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, vmware

Sorry for my spelling and grammar errors, english is not my native launguage.

I need to run `VMware-Player-3.1.5-491717.i386` in lubuntu. It has to be that version only, cause my motherboard architecture is 32bits. Thats why I cant use newer versions of vmware player.

I download this patch: `vmware workstation 7.1.5 / player 3.1.5 fix for linux 3.2+` (patch by Ariel), I extracted and put in in my home folder.

From this website: [weltall.heliohost.org](http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/)

My steps:

1) Ok, so I already install `VMware-Player-3.1.5-491717.i386`

2) If I start `VMware-Player-3.1.5-491717.i386` I get this error message:

```
VMware Kernel Module Updater, before you can run VMWare, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel.
```

3) Ok so time to use the patch

4) I put on terminal this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` 

 sudo chmod +x VMware-Player-3.1.5-491717.i386.bundle 

 sudo ./VMware-Player-3.1.5-491717.i386.bundle 

 sudo apt-get install patch 

 sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
```

5) It finish the hole process succesfully and it patch it. But when I try to run vmware player, I still get the same error. Before with old kernel it worked properly and I was able to run it with no problems. But with new Lubuntu kernel, now I get the error message, and wont get away.

```
VMware Kernel Module Updater, before you can run VMWare, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel
```

6) I noticed that the patch I download has 2 files:

a) `patch-modules_3.2.0.sh`

b) `vmware-715-kernel32.patch`

I am able to run `patch-modules_3.2.0.sh` properly, and I am able to install it succesfully, but I dont know how to install or run `vmware-715-kernel32.patch`.

I getting the feeling that, this is why I am getting the errors message, because I havent install properly the `vmware-715-kernel32.patch`

Any ideas of what command I need to run in the terminal in order to run `vmware-715-kernel32.patch`, and been able to patch the kernel succesfully ?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for patch an application is :

```
sudo patch `which [APPLICATION]` [DIRECTORY]/[PATCH FILE.patch]
```

In your case :

```
sudo patch `which vmware-player` [DIRECTORY]/vmware-715-kernel32.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the below command necessary to actually kick off the recompilations:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

(after patching of course)